# How to echo objects as string which is stored in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I want to echo cer_type from this array

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [cer_type] => S.L.C.
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 3
                [cer_type] => Intermediate
            )
    )
```

Comment: Is this a PHP question?

Comment: ya its for php..........need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    echo $array[0]->cer_type;

    // or if you want to loop through the array:

    foreach ($array as $element) {
        echo $element->cer_type;
    }
```